# How does memory barrier work?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, execution, instructions

Under Windows, there are three compiler-intrinsic functions to implement memory barrier:

```
1. _ReadBarrier;

2. _WriteBarrier;

3. _ReadWriteBarrier;
```

However, I found a weird problem: _ReadBarrier seems a dummy function doing nothing! The following is my assembly code generated by VC++ 2012.

My question is: How to implement a memory barrier function in assembly instructions?

```
int main()
{   
013EEE10  push        ebp  
013EEE11  mov         ebp,esp  
013EEE13  sub         esp,0CCh  
013EEE19  push        ebx  
013EEE1A  push        esi  
013EEE1B  push        edi  
013EEE1C  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
013EEE22  mov         ecx,33h  
013EEE27  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
013EEE2C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    int n = 0;
013EEE2E  mov         dword ptr [n],0  
    n = n + 1;
013EEE35  mov         eax,dword ptr [n]  
013EEE38  add         eax,1  
013EEE3B  mov         dword ptr [n],eax  
    _ReadBarrier();
    n = n + 1;
013EEE3E  mov         eax,dword ptr [n]  
013EEE41  add         eax,1  
013EEE44  mov         dword ptr [n],eax 
}
013EEE56  xor         eax,eax  
013EEE58  pop         edi  
013EEE59  pop         esi  
013EEE5A  pop         ebx  
013EEE5B  add         esp,0CCh  
013EEE61  cmp         ebp,esp  
013EEE63  call        __RTC_CheckEsp (013EC3B0h)  
013EEE68  mov         esp,ebp  
013EEE6A  pop         ebp  
013EEE6B  ret
```

Comment: On x86, all loads are acquires and all stores are releases, so you don't need any explicit code. The only necessary code is for a full barrier. The concept of a read barrier is more general than the x86 architecture, and it is non-trivial on machines with a weak memory model.

Comment: I'm guessing those are only compiler barriers to change how compiler generates code, rather than an assembly-level barrier.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is that really true, even for the most recent machines?  Doing so would slow things down considerably, and eliminate a lot of the utility of having multiple cores (at least for certain types of applications).

Comment: @JamesKanze: Hm, at least to the best of my knowledge. It's entirely possible that I'm mistaken about that, though.

Comment: a great explanation for linux kernel smp http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Comment: @KerrekSB: Are you saying that the `LFENCE` x86 instruction is effectively a no-op? http://www.rz.uni-karlsruhe.de/rz/docs/VTune/reference/vc153.htm

Comment: @KerrekSB Are you saying that if x86 core A writes to memory location M1 and M2, then another core loading M1 and M2 will see the writes in that order without any explicit barriers?

Comment: @KerrekSB It doesn't correspond to what I seem to remember having read (but all of my real experience in this domain has been on Sparcs, where the only barriers are those you provide).  This would mean that when reading bytes (sequentially), the hardware cannot convert them into word reads if there is any memory access whatever between the reads.

Comment: @JamesKanze: For *aligned* loads and stores, I should add. Non-aligned operations (which x86 allows) are most certainly not atomic.

Comment: @NPE: `LFENCE` seems to be more general. I was only referring to acquire-release semantics that load and store a single memory location, i.e. a store to location `x` synchronizes-with a load from the same location `x`. Also note that you still need to tell the *compiler* that the ordering is important, which is what the compiler intrinsics do.

Comment: For interest's sake, take a look at the implementation of the Posix spinlock on x86 and see if that contains any "special" instructions or lock prefixes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`_ReadBarrier`, `_WriteBarrier`, and `_ReadWriteBarrier` are [intrinsics that affect how the compiler can reorder code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/f20w0x5e.aspx); they have absolutely nothing to do with CPU memory barriers and are only valid for specific kinds of memory (see "Affected Memory" [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

[`MemoryBarrier()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the intrinsic that you use to force a CPU memory barrier. However, the recommendation from Microsoft is to use `std::atomic<T>` going forward with VC++.

Answer (score 5):

Modern processors are capable of executing instructions quite a long way ahead of where it actually is "completing" the instructions, so memory barriers are used to prevent it from running to far ahead when it comes to certain types of memory operations, where strict ordering is required - for most things, it doesn't actually matter if you write to variable a before variable b, or b before a. But sometimes it does.

The x86 instruction set has `lfence`, `sfence` and `fence`, which are instructions that "fence in" loads, stores and all memory operations respectively. The point about a "fence" or "barrier" instruction is to **ensure** that all the instructions that precede the barrier instruction has completed their loads, stores or both before the next instruction after the barrier can continue.

This is important if you are implementing for example semaphores, mutexes or similar instructions, since it's important to store the value saying "I've locked the semaphore" before you continue to read other data, for example. Otherwise things can go wrong, let's say.

Note that unless you REALLY know what you are doing with memory barriers, it's probably best to NOT use them - and rely on already existing code that solves the same problem - `std::atomic` are one place to fund such code. I have written quite a bit of "tricky" code, but only once or twice have I needed a memory barrier in my code.

Several times, I've needed to make the compiler not spread the code around, which you can do with "no-op functions", and apparently there are even special intrinsic functions these days to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are several important points to consider.  Perhaps the
first is that barriers only have an effect in multithreaded
code, and most compilers require a special option to produce
multithreaded code.  And things like `_ReadBarrier` are almost
certainly compiler built-ins, and *should* do nothing unless
you've given the options for multithreaded code.

The second is that what the hardware requires, even in a
multithreaded context, varies.  On most of the machines I've
worked on (over some forty years), the machine never required
anything; barriers only become relevant if the machine has
sophisticated read and write pipelines.  (Most earlier machines
didn't even have fence or barrier instructions, so the generated
code would have to be empty.)

Comment: Memory barriers are also relevant for low-level hardware access.

Comment: @edgar.holleis True.  That doesn't affect user processes, of course, but the real criteria isn't threads, it's the possibility of two entities accesses the memory.  Threads are just the most frequent case in which this occurs.